# Check if a list have the same element in Excel

Tags: excel

I would like to check if in Excel column I have two same element.
Basically my aim is to write every time a word in a new cell but I want excel to advise me if I already put the same word.

Something like this:
If I am writing again "dog" I want excel to tell me something.

[image]

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You've described the desired result, what have you tried to achieve it and what problem did you encounter? Seems to me this could be done with conditional formatting

Comment: Like nomad mentioned, just create a conditional format rule to highlight duplicates. The default rule will change the cell color to pink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Excel 2016

- Highlight the entire column
- Click on "Home"
- Click on "Conditional Formatting"
- Click on "Highlight Cells Rules"
- Click on "Duplicate Values"
- Click on "Ok"

[image]

Now enter `dog` in same column, both instances of "dog" will highlight red.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That's built-in!
See: Conditional formatting / highlight cell rules / Duplicate values